# Почему после некоторой операции одна из веток узла ссылается на саму себя?

Tags: c++

Cтруктура node имеет в своих полях указатели на node

```cpp
struct node {
    node() {};
    frequency data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

В программе после того, как я добавляю один экземпляр переменной типа node, ее правый узел ссылается сам на себя (хранит те же данные, что и сама переменная)

```
while (nodes.size() > 2) { // формирование дерева
        node *n1 = new node; // извлекаемые узлы
        node *n2 = new node;
        n1 = &nodes[nodes.size() - 1];
        n2 = &nodes[nodes.size() - 2];

        nodes.pop_back();
        nodes.pop_back();

        node n; // новый узел, соединяющий два извлеченных узла с их суммарной частотой
        n.data.c.second = n1->data.c.second + n2->data.c.second;
        n.left = n1;
        n.right = n2;

        nodes.push_back (n); // после этой операции n.right копирует n

        int i = nodes.size() - 1;
        while (i > 1 && nodes[i].data.c.second > nodes[i - 1].data.c.second)
            swap (nodes[i], nodes[i - 1]);
    }
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: `node *n1 = new node; n1 = &nodes[nodes.size() - 1];` - это полная бессмыслица. Зачем вы выделяли память, чтобы сразу ее выкинуть?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что вы используете `n1, n2`, которые только что удалили через `pop_back()`